# How to use date comparison with Today() in Excel array formula?

Tags: excel

I have this array formula:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(Overview!E:E;{"<=2020-04-22"};Overview!F:F;{"Working";"Review"}))}
```

It works. But when changing the date to TODAY() function, it breaks. This does not work, says error in formula:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(Overview!E:E;{"<=" & TODAY()};Overview!F:F;{"Working";"Review"}))}
```

How can I enter the TODAY() into the array formula for date comparison? I think it has something to do with the quotes, but double or triple quoting does not help.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Overview!E:E;"<=" & TODAY();Overview!F:F;{"Working";"Review"}))` ?

Comment: Yes, for single date as a criteria it works. However I need it to work for array of dates inside the {}. Like this `=SUM(COUNTIFS(Overview!E:E;{"<=2020-04-22";">=2020-03-20"};Overview!F:F;{"Working";"Review"}))`

Comment: I think the formula can be inserted only via VBA as:
`"=SUM(COUNTIFS(Overview!C[3],{""<=" & Date & """;"">=2020-03-20""},Overview!C[4],{""Working"";""Review""}))"`

Comment: There might be a way but could you not just add an extra condition?

Comment: It will be a complicated formula with three ranges and up to 10 criteria per range. However, I have the solution:
`{"""<="" & TODAY() &"""""}`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this can be done with extra pair of quotes (five pairs in total):

```
{"""<="" & TODAY() &"""""}
```